# How to use pipe in perl

Tags: perl, pipe, pstree

My syntax is

```
my $pstree = `pstree -p $pid|wc`;
```

but i am getting an error.

```
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `$pid` isn't just a number; it probably has a trailing newline character.

See it with:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Data::Dumper->new([$pid])->Terse(1)->Useqq(1)->Dump;
```

Comment: `print Dumper($pid)` probably would have been sufficient.

Comment: @jordanm: no, Useqq is important for showing non-printable characters

Answer (score 1):

It's valid perl, your shell is what is complaining. Did you put the #!/bin/perl at the top of the script? It's probably being interpreted by bash, not perl.

```
host:/var/tmp root# ./try.pl
5992  zsched
  6875  /usr/local/sbin/sshd -f /usr/local/etc/sshd_config
    3691  /usr/local/sbin/sshd -f /usr/local/etc/sshd_config -R
      3711  -tcsh
        6084  top 60
===
       5      16     175


host:/var/tmp root# cat try.pl 
#!/bin/perl

my $pstree = `ptree 3691`;
my $wc = `ptree 3691 | wc`;
print STDOUT $pstree;
print STDOUT "===\n";
print STDOUT $wc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the shell to do your counting, you can use Perl, which saves you a process and some complexity in your shell command:

```
my $count = () = qx(pstree -p $pid);
```

`qx()` does the same thing as backticks. The empty parentheses puts the `qx()` in list context, which makes it return a list, which then in scalar context is the size. It is a shortcut for:

```
my @list  = qx(pstree -p $pid);
my $count = @list;
```

Comment: wc counts characters, words, and lines (with no command switches)